# https - with apache for google app engine and python script is not working

Tags: python, apache, google-app-engine, ssl, https

I have Google App Engine and Python running on `http://localhost`, which is fine working. But for making it reliably working i need to add https, Google App Engine do not have it.

So i have been trying stunnel and apache to make https working. I tried following but its still not working.

```
NameVirtualHost example.stackoverflow.com:443
<VirtualHost example.stackoverflow.com:443>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLProxyEngine On
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  #ProxyRequests Off

  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/stunnel/a.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/stunnel/a.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/stunnel/b.ca

  ServerName localhost
  ProxyPass / http://localhost
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost
  #ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /MYSITE/ /
  CacheDisable *
</VirtualHost>
```

when a user visit: https://example.stackoverflow.com, basically his browser address get changed from https:// to http://example.stackoverflow.com and he is able to use the Google App Engine and Python instances.

But i need to have https for Google App Engine with my python. How can i resolve it please?

**EDIT:** secure is used but still not working

```
application: rtc
version: 6
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /html
  static_dir: html

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /.*
  script: rtc.app
  secure: always

inbound_services:
- channel_presence

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google App Engine does support HTTPS, you just need to sign up for it.  It is not free, but it isn't too expensive either.

More information on the types of SSL provided is available at: [SSL for a Custom Domain](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl).

Also, if you want to automatically redirect users to the secure site, you can use the `secure` keyword in Google App Engine's `app.yaml` configuration file.  See [Secure URLs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Secure_URLs).

Comment: Providing HTTPS costs money no matter how you do it.  To provide HTTPS you need to purchase an SSL certificate from a certificate authority. Even if you're using apache, you'll need to buy a certificate.  HTTPS does not work on the app engine development server, have you tried it on a production server?

Comment: I don't understand the remaining issue here.  On GAE, you can purchase SSL. If you are unwilling to pay Google, you can also use http://wwwizer.com/, which provides similar functionality.